# Nominatim does not respect countrycode

Tags: geocoding, api, nominatim

[Possible duplicate](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/132140/limit-nominatim-results-tp-specific-country)

I have a question about Nominatim, but the OSM forum currently does not accept new registrations...

I want to limit my search results to a specific country, so I am using the following snippet (minimal example):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import requests
import json
import pprint

#r = requests.post('http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/', params={
#        'format': 'json', 'city': 'Athens', 'country': 'Greece'})
r = requests.post('http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/', params={
        'format': 'json', 'q': 'Athens', 'countrycode': 'gr'})                                                                                               
result = json.loads(r.text)
pprint.pprint(result)
```

Using the general query and *countrycode*, the results are all of cities named Athens in the United States.
Using the structured request query, the result is as expected.

The [wiki](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim#Parameters) states that using *countrycode* limits the results to a specific set of countries.

I am aware that I can use the structured requests API instead of a general query, but I have some misgivings as it is labeled as experimental. However, my question is if *countrycode* is respected or is it me that is doing something wrong here?